# jquery .click function not firing on pressing button. Have to click many times

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.badge_button > .more').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#window').fadeIn();
        $("#window").empty().html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
        $('#window').load('badge.php', {id:id});
        $.scrollTo( '#window', 200 );

});
});
```

and this html :

```
<div class = 'badge_button'><a href='#' id = '1' class='more'>More</a></div>
```

My problem is that I have to click the "more" button many times before it actually fires. This happens on and off. Is it because of the default behavior or does it have to do with `href='#'`?

Comment: You need to return false; or preventDefault in your click, else it will still refresh the site with the hashtag. So you click once, it refreshes, you click twice - its already there - and shows the function. Atleast my theory :)

Comment: what is the control with id window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think not adding `return false;` is the problem. You need it because the `href=#` reloads the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.badge_button > .more').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#window').fadeIn();
        $("#window").empty().html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
        $('#window').load('badge.php', {id:id});
        $.scrollTo( '#window', 200 );
        return false;
});
});
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: someone gave everyone a minus 1...fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Yes your Jquery logic is fine but `href=#` is reloading the page.

Just add the `return false;` in your Jquery logic.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.badge_button > .more').click(function() {
             var id = $(this).attr('id');
             $('#window').fadeIn();
             $("#window").empty().html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
             $('#window').load('badge.php', {id:id});
             $.scrollTo( '#window', 200 );
             return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: some people just copy your own answers with 6 minutes of delay... just saying... lol

Comment: someone gave everyone a minus 1...fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the problem is the reference to the window object (hopefully which you are trying to refer).

In that case your code should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.badge_button > .more').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(window).fadeIn();
        $(window).empty().html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
        $(window).load('badge.php', {id:id});
        $.scrollTo( window, 200 );
        });
});
```

Look at the way you are referring to the document while binding the event.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BZBsU/): look at the error console you will now find an error saying page not found as that page does not exist on the server. hopefully it should work on your site.

Also a quick suggestion you can get rid of document.ready and instead use the live handler. Something like:

```
$('div.badge_button > .more').live("click",function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(window).fadeIn();
        $(window).empty().html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
        $(window).load('badge.php', {id:id});
        $.scrollTo( window, 200 );
        });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't know who has been giving everyone -1